# C++ multiple definitions detected in code blocks

Tags: codeblocks

I am facing this problem. I tried to change the version of code block. It doesn't work. I was just created a header file and another source file to implement the header file class. But the multiple definitions is detected problem is showing. Please help ne solve this problem.
[***enter image description here***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPvDi.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "I doubt most users posting like this will bother to read your link, respond or bother to edit the post"—but surely they'll click a link to that image, right :-)? In any case, yeah, it's not a clear violation. But especially with new users I like to err on the side of being welcoming. You might have seen a hundred people posting images of text and think of that as a meme, but this is likely one of OP's very first interactions on SO and they may not view it from the same perspective.